# Is there a way to autosave after every 2-5 mins in sublime text?

Tags: sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I have come across ways to save on focus up `"save_on_focus_lost": true,`
or save on every change like this https://packagecontrol.io/packages/auto-save
but I am looking for time based saving where the code doesn't save too frequently like above methods but only after say every 5 mins.

Comment: Not the answer you want, but once many years ago I got burnt by losing a lot of changes made between Microsoft Word's automatic saves (which I think have a threshold of about 5 mins). Since that day I made it a habit to press Ctrl+S after each change or set of changes I made. Now it doesn't matter whether I'm using Word for documents, VS Code for code or Sublime Text for text editing, I save changes without even realising that I have, and have never lost more than a minute's worth of work since then.